# How to install cardano-node and cardano-cli on Mac M1

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, cardano-node, cabal

I tried to install `cardano-cli` and `cardano-node` using this [documentation](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#macos) and stuck on below step

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/bin
cp -p "$(./scripts/bin-path.sh cardano-node)" $HOME/.local/bin/
cp -p "$(./scripts/bin-path.sh cardano-cli)" $HOME/.local/bin/
```

that shows an error like these

[image]

anyone with Mac has solved this?

Comment: These means that you didn't complied cardano-node properly. Try to run again `cabal build all` and put here what error you are getting if any.

Comment: FYI `cabal build cardano-node cardano-cli` takes a while to run. If it appears to completes quickly then there is an error. If there is an error you should see a message displayed - we will need to see that message to help further. It would also pay to make sure that all of the environment variables noted in the guide that you are following are set correctly before running `cabal build cardano-node cardano-cli`.

Comment: here it is @os11k, please see this screenshot also https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMkGs.png

Comment: Don't use print-screen for sharing error messages, these is really inconvenient. I would recommend to delete cardano-node directory and start from scratch

Comment: How sure are you that all previous steps in the guide completed successfully?
I would step through the guide again from the start and make sure there are not issues after each step.
Some errors/failures are subtle.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is much easier:

- go to https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases
- expand the "Downloads" for the latest release
- click on "Hydra binaries"
- click on "cardano-node-macos", which for the 1.34.1 version points to https://hydra.iohk.io/build/13065616
- download the binary distribution (https://hydra.iohk.io/build/13065616/download/1/cardano-node-1.34.1-macos.tar.gz)
- extract the file and copy the extracted binaries to /usr/local/bin or ~/.local/bin

There is no need to compile the binaries on your mac. Why would you? Are you compiling every program you install on your mac?

Comment: the latest versions (such as the current 1.35.3) are only available for compilation. Also, you would need to compile the sources for Mac M1 users as these aren't available at all for download from hydra build servers as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful using nix for this task, if you are open to it.  Here's how I set up nix on a Mac M1 (note that this post is a bit old, so YMMV):
https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/mmzut6/macos_plutus_playground_build_instructions/ .  Only the first 6 steps are so are nix-specific, the rest are for building plutus.

then you can proceed with building the `cardano-node` and `cardano-cli` executables:

```
nix-build -A cardano-node -o result/mainnet/cardano-node
nix-build -A cardano-cli -o result/mainnet/cardano-cli
```

this page also has info, tho I have not used it specifically it might be helpful:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.md#building-and-running-with-nix